# Magento 2 - AWS Lightsail - Bitnami - Password protect development site

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, passwords, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have followed the below link and added authentication for Bitnami Magento 2.3.2 development site which is in AWS Lightsail.

https://docs.bitnami.com/bch/apps/magento/administration/use-htpasswd/

I have created htpasswd and magento_users using,

```
cd /opt/bitnami
apache2/bin/htpasswd -cb apache2/magento_users USERNAME PASSWORD
```

Also I have added the below code in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/conf/httpd-app.conf

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs">
...
AuthType Basic
AuthName MyAuthName
AuthUserFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/magento_users"
Require valid-user
...
<IfVersion >= 2.3>
# Require all granted
</IfVersion>
...
</Directory>
```

After I have restarted the apache and flushed the cache, It asked for username and password when loading dev frontend. When I provide credentials, it end up getting error as,

```
Error 503 Backend fetch failed
Backend fetch failed

Guru Meditation:
XID: 393256

Varnish cache server
```

I can't see anything related to this in Apache error_log.

Can anyone please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Please note that we configure Varnish to serve the Magento's files. If you add that Basic authentication configuration, Varnish won't be able to connect to Apache to get the information and that's why you are getting that error. If you want to add a Basic auth method in Apache, you will need to [disable Varnish](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/magento/administration/configure-use-varnish/#disable-varnish-tm) and configure Apache to work using the port 80 (/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf and /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf). I hope this helps

Comment: @JotaMartos Thank you so much for you reply. I have tried your solution. I disabled Varnish and configured apache to use port 80 (Followed - https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/processmakerenterprise/administration/configure-port/), but when I restart the apache, httpd is still starting at port 81. I also tried `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:80)`.

Comment: the Bitnami control script (ctlscript.sh) shows that Apache is running in the port 81 but if you changed the conf/httpd.conf and conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf files, Apache should be running in the port 80. Can you take a look at the /opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh script and change the port information there?